# Ngrx and resolvers with HttpClient in Angular 6

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, ngrx-entity, angular-resolver

I'm using ngrx / (store, effects) in Angular 6.
I have the problem in the resolution of one of the routing variables by a resolver.
Here the code and the explanation

**Resolver**

```
@Injectable()
export class HkSpecialitiesResolver implements Resolve<Speciality[]> {

  constructor(
    private store: Store<AppState>) {
  }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Speciality[]> {
    return this.store
      .pipe(
        select(selectAllSpecialities),
        tap(specialities => {
          if (!specialities || specialities.length === 0) {
            this.store.dispatch(new AllSpecialitiesRequested());
          }
        }),
        filter((specialities: Speciality[]) => {
          return specialities !== [];
        }),
        take(select(selectAllSpecialities).length)
      );
  }
}
```

**Effects**

```
@Injectable()
export class HkSpecialitiesEffects {

  @Effect()
  loadAllSpecilities$ = this.actions$
    .pipe(
      ofType<AllSpecialitiesRequested>(SpecialityActionTypes.AllSpecialitiesRequested),
      withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(allSpecialitiesLoaded))),
      filter(([action, allSpecialitiesLoaded]) => {
        console.log('loadAllSpecilities$ - ', [action, allSpecialitiesLoaded]);
        return !allSpecialitiesLoaded;
      }),
      mergeMap((o) => {
        console.log('loadAllSpecilities$ - mergeMap', o);
        return this.specialityService.findAll();
      }),
      map((specialities: Speciality[]) => {
        console.log('loadAllCourses$ - map', specialities);
        return new AllSpecialitiesLoaded({specialities});
      })
    );

  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private specialityService: HkSpecialitiesService,
              private store: Store<AppState>) {

  }
}
```

**Reducer**

```
export interface SpecialitiesState extends EntityState<Speciality> {
  allSpecialitiesLoaded: boolean;
}

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<Speciality> =
  createEntityAdapter<Speciality>({
    selectId: (speciality: Speciality)  =>  {
      return (speciality !== undefined) ? speciality.uuid : undefined;
    }
  });


export const initialSpecialitiesState: SpecialitiesState = adapter.getInitialState({
  allSpecialitiesLoaded: false
});


export function specialityReducer(state = initialSpecialitiesState, action: SpecialityActions): SpecialitiesState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SpecialityActionTypes.SpecialityLoaded:
      return adapter.addOne(action.payload.speciality, state);
    case SpecialityActionTypes.AllSpecialitiesLoaded:
      return adapter.addAll(action.payload.specialities, {...state, allSpecialitiesLoaded: true});
    case SpecialityActionTypes.SpecialitySaved:
      return adapter.updateOne(action.payload.speciality, state);
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}

export const {
  selectAll,
  selectEntities,
  selectIds,
  selectTotal

} = adapter.getSelectors();
```

**Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class HkSpecialitiesService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  findAll(): Observable<Speciality[]> {
    const vm = this;
    // it works with these lines
    /*return Observable.create((observer) => {
  observer.next([{id: 'a', uuid: 'a', name: 'Psychology', description: 'Psychology'}]);
});*/
    // Not works with this line
    return vm.http.get<Speciality[]>('/api/specialities').pipe(map((specialities) => specialities));
  }
}
```

The problem is that just as the code is, the resolves specialities variable is resolved as empty ([]), in the component I get it empty, an empty array.
But if in the service, I change the http invocation, for the line that is commented, the resolution of the variable in the resolver takes the only correct value that I am returning.

The "Resolver" is resolved before the effect ends, when in the service it invokes the get of the http.

What I do not understand is that the commented line (with which everything works) returns an observable with the same content as that of the http invocation.

Any suggestions?